# Правильно ли я сделал inputы с поиском

Tags: html, css, form

Я сделал следующую форму для тренировки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: правильно ли я все спозиционировал или есть более валидные способы?
Например элемент `::after` для иконки у кнопки я спозиционировал по центру с пикселями, так как знал его размеры. Будет ли такой код считаться валидным, если бы я сдавал его заказчику?
Надеюсь правильно сформулировал, заранее спасибо!

`html:`

```
 <div class="tracking-form-inputs">
    <div class="tracking-form_num">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите номер отслеживания">
    </div>
    <div class="tracking-form_btn">
        <input type="submit" value="Начать поиск">
    </div>
    <p>Например: RB325762338CN</p>
</div>
```

`css:`

```
.tracking-form-inputs {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tracking-form_num {
    input {
        width: 570px;
        height: 70px;
        padding-left: 24px;
        background: #F5F7FC;
        color: #A1ACC3;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #DBE1ED;
        border-radius: 8px;
        outline: none;
        &::placeholder {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #A1ACC3;
        }

    }
}

tracking-form_btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    input {
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0 17px 0 43px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background: #519DFF;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 14px;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    &::after {
        content: url('../imgs/icons/search-icon.png');
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        left: 17px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Инпуты стоит оборачивать в тег form. Также у каждого инпута должен быть label.

```
<form action="">
  <span>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <label for="name">Имя</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input id="surname" type="text">
    <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
  </span>
</form>
```

А насчет валидации - не думаю, что твоему заказчику будет дело до того, как там твой код устроен, ему важно то, как этот выглядит и работает.
В интернете есть множество валидаторов. Вот один из них: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea
Он выведет тебе ошибки твоего кода и скажет, как исправить

Comment: а все инпуты надо в form оборачивать? и без label никак?

Comment: В некоторых случаях можно и не оборачивать инпуты, но если ты планируешь отправлять данные из инпутов на backend, то тег form необходим. Если тебе мешает лейбл, то просто сделай его визуально-скрытым. Вот статья: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/boost/frontend/short-12

Comment: а без form никак не отправить данные на бэкэнд? А зачем нужен тогда label, если его скрывать?

Comment: @BearVorkuta, ну без лейблов можно, но если вы хотите сделать поля доступными юзайте лейблы, можете как вариант их визуально спрятать(для скринридеров одним словом). Как уже Андрей сказал выше.

Comment: Да я просто вставил кусок кода, по которому вопрос был, я знаю про form. Лейбл нужен, что бы при клике на текст фокус переходил на инпут - https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-label-tag.html. Мне по макету не нужно было.
Просто я сделал, оно вроде работает, но насколько технически правильно я прописал css код я вот неуверен. Возможно я просто замарачиваюсь )